# PyQgis api returns wrong layer CRS

Tags: qgis-2.2, pyqgis

I have shape vector layer in ESPG:3859 CRS. I try to get layer crs

```
layer.crs.geographicCRSAuthId()
```

but method always returns EPSG:4326 no matters which CRS I chose in layer properties.

.qpj file for shape layer:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH],EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
```

.prj

```
PROJCS["WGS_84_Pseudo_Mercator",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Mercator"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0.0]]
```

Comment: Can you insert the content of the .prj file?

Comment: Yep, I have edited original message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for the ID of the **geographic** CRS, and that is correctly EPSG:4326 in your case:

```
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

as you find before the projection parameters.

Geographic CRS is lat/lon degrees, and the basis for the **projection** to Mercator, Transverse Mercator or whatever projection is used.

You may intend to ask for `layer.crs.authid()` instead.

Comment: I have mistaken, and add .qpj instead of .prj I have added them both. Any way shape was created in QGIS and .prj and.qpj also creted with QGIS. I have tried to export layer to geo json without any reprojection, and coordinates seems to be with 3857.

Comment: shouldn't it be layer.crs().authid() ?

Comment: @chenghopan probably yes, but I don't know the code around that line in detail.