# Setting CRS in QGIS using PyQGIS?

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis

This question is very similar to [How to define layer's CRS and avoid the CRS dialog in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136378), but it's doesn't work for me.

This is my try:

```
vlayer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(25830))
iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().setDestinationCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(25830))
```

But the dialog pop up  asking for CRS to choose, and when I ask for the CRS of the layer, it show a diferent CRS:

```
print "CRS: " + vlayer.crs().geographicCRSAuthId()
```

It show **CRS: EPSG:4258** and It must be **25830**

Comment: Perhaps this post might give you more insight: [PyQgis api returns wrong layer CRS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102037/pyqgis-api-returns-wrong-layer-crs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry. I was in a mistake:

The current CRS is get by *authid()* method, not *geographicCRSAuthId()*

On the other hand, I wanted to avoid the CRS Dialog when I load a vector layer from pyQGIS.

Similar questions are been asked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136378/how-to-define-layers-crs-and-avoid-the-crs-dialog-in-pyqgis)  and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68167/how-to-avoid-the-crs-dialog-when-creating-a-vector-layer-memory) . I have got the results setting QGIS like: Setting>Options>CRS ->Use CRS of project

And I put my snippet of code to load a PostGIS view like a vector layer: (please, let me know if I am in a mistake)

```
mycrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(25830)#If not specified otherwise in second parameter, PostGIS SRID is used by default.
iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().setDestinationCrs(mycrs)# set CRS to canvas
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection('localhost', '5432', '-mydb-', '-myname-', '-mypasswd-')
uri.setDataSource('public', '-my table/view-', 'the_geom')
uri.setKeyColumn('id')# neccesary for postgres views who doesn't support primary key
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), '-nameofmyvectorlayer-', 'postgres')
vlayer.setCrs(mycrs,True)#set CRS to vector layer. I'm not sure True param. is neccesary
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

When I load the vector layer a Warning Message appears telling that: CRS is not defined, and will be used the CRS of the project...and it works.

Comment: I have the same issue. Although I set up crs, I see this warning message from qgis. I made a dirty warkaround and removed this warning: ```iface.messageBar().popWidget()```